# AccessDeniedException: 403 when creating bucket using gsutil

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create bucket using gsutil provided by kubernetes.

Below is the response -

```
$ gsutil mb -c nearline -p kubetest  gs://some-bucket
Creating gs://some-bucket/...
AccessDeniedException: 403 hello.user@gmail.com does not have storage.buckets.create access to bucket some-bucket.
```

I tried the above because when trying run kuberentes on bare metal failed with below exception.

```
$ cluster/kube-up.sh 
... Starting cluster in us-central1-b using provider gce
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling verify-kube-binaries
... calling kube-up
Project: kubetest
Network Project: kubetest
Zone: us-central1-b
BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://kubernetes-staging-9e9580a659 bucket does not exist.
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-9e9580a659
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-9e9580a659/...
AccessDeniedException: 403 hello.user@gmail.com does not have storage.buckets.create access to bucket kubernetes-staging-9e9580a659.
```

How can I resolve this error and give access to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Got to cloud shell and use the command - `gsutil config -b`

The **gsutil config** command obtains access credentials for Google Cloud Storage and writes a **boto/gsutil**  configuration file containing the obtained credentials along with a number of other configuration-controllable values and the flag **-b**  causes gsutil config  to launch a browser to obtain OAuth2 approval.

It prompts a URL. [ **Hit Allow** ]

In your browser you should see a page that requests you to authorize access to Google Cloud Platform APIs and Services on your behalf. After you approve, an authorization code will be displayed.

**Copy the verification code and paste to terminal** and hit enter

This should resolve the 403.